Sliding menu in libgdx java android
I am trying to create a side sliding menu similar to Android's NavigationView in libgdx the problem when I try to close by sliding to the left the menu closes quickly and I want it to close gradually depending on the sliding handled by GestureListener.



import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
  private Stage stage;
  private Table menuTable;
  private boolean isMenuOpen = false;
  private float startX;
  private float initialX;
  private boolean isDraggingFromEdge = false;

  @Override
  public void create() {
    stage = new Stage();
    menuTable = new Table();
    initialX = -Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2;

    menuTable.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    menuTable.setPosition(initialX, 0);
    menuTable.left().top();

    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    pixmap.fill();
    Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap);
    TextureRegionDrawable textureRegionDrawable =
        new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(texture));
    menuTable.setBackground(textureRegionDrawable);
    pixmap.dispose();

    menuTable.add(new Label("Opción 1", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE))).row();
    menuTable.add(new Label("Opción 2", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE))).row();

    stage.addActor(menuTable);

    GestureDetector gestureDetector =
        new GestureDetector(
            new GestureDetector.GestureAdapter() {
              @Override
              public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                isDraggingFromEdge = x < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.05 && !isMenuOpen;
                if (isDraggingFromEdge) {
                  isDraggingFromEdge = true;
                  startX = x;
                  return true;
                } else if (isMenuOpen && x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 20) {
                  isDraggingFromEdge = true;
                  startX = x;
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              }

              @Override
              public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
                if (isDraggingFromEdge) {

                  float cx = x - startX;
                  float newX = initialX + cx;

                  if (newX > 0) newX = 0;
                  if (newX < initialX) newX = initialX;
                  menuTable.setPosition(newX, 0);
                }
                return true;
              }

              @Override
              public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                if (isDraggingFromEdge) {
                  float currentX = menuTable.getX();
                  if (currentX > initialX / 2) {

                    menuTable.addAction(Actions.moveTo(0, 0, 0.5f));
                    isMenuOpen = true;
                  } else {

                    menuTable.addAction(Actions.moveTo(initialX, 0, 0.5f));
                    isMenuOpen = false;
                  }
                  isDraggingFromEdge = false;
                }
                return true;
              }
            });

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gestureDetector);
  }

  @Override
  public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
  }

  @Override
  public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();
  }
}



And I want it to change size as I slide to the left so that it doesn't close abruptly.
